# Rails 3: Using a different gemset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using RVM but I'm having some problems. How can I start using another gemset, and which one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
rvm gemset create rails3
rvm gemset use rails3
```

This would create a gemset called rails3 and then use it. Check out the documentation [here](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/gemsets/basics/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

**You can switch to a specific gemset with**
rvm @gemname
**And see which gemsets are in your "box" with**
rvm gemset list